# Text box and button on a image in MVC using responsive web design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, css, responsive-design

I have to create an MVC web for my company and I'm using a responsive web design framework (Zurb Foundation). It works amazing. But my problem is I have an image in one of the divs and I need to add a textbox and a button into the image (basically it's a login). I wanted a kind of control, with the background image and then the html textbox/button, but not sure if this is possible in MVC.

I tried with css (position:absolute) but when I re-size the page to let the html adapts to the different browser sizes, it doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: A textbox and button IN an image? Uhmm. Photoshop?

Comment: Thanks Bondye. That was my first idea, but I need to use the text and button html functionality. Is it possible to get that using photoshop?

Comment: I don't understand what you realy want. But I guess [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/6x5gg/)

Comment: Thanks again. That's right, that is exactly what I want. I was able to get it with the same css, the problem is when using the responsive web design framework, the image changes but the text box doesn't.

Comment: Change in what? You want the textbox to become smaller? Bigger? Disapear?

Comment: Smaller or bigger, it depends :) See this example, http://foundation.zurb.com/prototyping.php and resize your browser, see how the big image changes? Image now my text box and button on that image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaaah, I got it now.

You need to understand `position` for this.

[Some information](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

An absolute positioned element in a relative positioned element...

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6x5gg/2/)

Just play some with the margin, breaks etc...

Comment: Problem was at the moment to resize the page with the framework, and I thought that was because of the framework itself. But with you info and use of css media queries, it works. Thanks!